# How can I find out what kind of wireless card I have from output of lspci

Tags: drivers, wifi

I am trying to install a wireless driver for a new laptop running `ubuntu 12.04`.

If I run `lspci` I do not see any human readable mention of a wireless card.

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 0a0c (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-V (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5227 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 818b
abe-lens-laptop@abe:~$ lspci | wireless
wireless: command not found
```

But if I `grep` for "0280", which ubuntu help forums say will show me `lspci` output for wireless cards, I do get machine-readable output that does not mean much to me.

```
$ lspci -nm | grep 0280
03:00.0 "0280" "10ec" "818b" "10ec" "001b"
```

How can I find out what kind of wireless card I have?

Comment: you forget the grep on your `lspci | wireless` but still with that result will not be correct lspci -vv would maybe be more useful

Comment: Run `lspci -vnns 03:00.0`

Answer (score 3):

And at least, maybe *lshw* (you have to install it before) should give you a readable answer.

On my machine, under the section "network":

```
description: Wireless interface
product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
[...]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `-v` switch with `lspci` you can get the name of the network card you have.

#### Example

```
$ lspci -v | grep -A 10 -i "Network Controller"
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at f2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

0d:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2133
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f2500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
```

I have a Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN network card in my system.

**NOTE:** If you want even more info about a device add additional `-vv` switches to `lspci`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ubuntu Bug 1239578](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1239578), that'd be a RTL8192EE. The latest status appears to be that there are some possibly-working beta drivers around, but no official release yet.

(I found that through two Google searches: one for *realtek 818b* and another for *10ec 818b*. `10ec` is a vendor ID for Realtek. `818b` is the device ID assigned by Realtek. Searches along those lines work for pretty much any PCI/PCI-X/PCIe device.)