# Wifi not working on Ubuntu-Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: ubuntu, internet, network-interface

I have HP Split 13 x2 laptop with Ubuntu 15.04 alongside with Windows 10. When I use Ubuntu, my network connections are shown to be disabled. No Wifi, No wired connections!

The network adapter is Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter and Wifi is Intel(R) Wireless- N 7260

Output of `lshw`:

```
 *-network DISABLED
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 7260
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 73
                serial: 0c:8b:fd:57:2c:a4
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-15-generic firmware=25.15.12.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:46 memory:b2400000-b2401fff
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a1e (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
```

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 04f3:0116 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 064e:c352 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 06cb:5711 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:0976 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: "Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter" isn't real. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/what-is-microsoft-kernel-debug-network-adapter/f72b8408-e4f7-4593-9e18-8cbb3e38a5ad?auth=1

Comment: Could you post the output of `lshw` and/or `lspci` and `lsusb` (depending on what type of devices these network adapters are)?  See e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116140/how-can-i-find-out-what-kind-of-wireless-card-i-have-from-output-of-lspci

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/341690/ethernet-network-disabled

Comment: It didn't work! It says not able to perform because of RF Kill. Thanks